# Wrong placement of button inside linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, orientation

I have three textviews with drawableleft on them in horizontal orientation of linear layout and trying to show first @+id/tv_video_call view then tv_language and showing correctly on the android studio preview and does not change its position inside the class.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_video_call"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_video"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Video Call"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textScaleX="1.2"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/vertical_line"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_language"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_language"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_logout"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_language"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/logout"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textScaleX="1.2"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <View
                    android:id="@+id/logoutline"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_language"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_logout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logouticon"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/logout"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textScaleX="1.2"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

but the emulator is showing the first textview after the second one having no idea what causes it to shift to that place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set buttons width with 0dp and set **weight** to 1 for them to divide equally in the layout.

Right now you have set width to wrap content which means that if those 2 buttons can't fit at the same time, one of them will be shift out.

Comment: it does not work.It shows the same behavior even  after applying weights.

Comment: Then your problem must be in the rest of the layout, be careful with wrap content elements.